# AWS CLI: Not able to filter describe-rules

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-cli

I am trying to get the list of listener rules based on a filter as described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output.html

Below is my command:

```
aws elbv2 describe-rules \
--listener-arn arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:34555433333:listener/app/ApplicationLoadBalancer/a333ddsdsddsds/22assds3dasfd \
--filters "TargetGroupArn==arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:34555433333:targetgroup/TG-Test-111111111/ass22dss2dkk" \
--query 'Rules[].RuleArn'
```

when I run it I keep getting:
`Unknown options: --filters, TargetGroupArn==`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get a list of listener rule you can use query, is there any need of filter with query?

```
aws elbv2 describe-rules --listener-arn arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:34555433333:listener/app/ApplicationLoadBalancer/a333ddsdsddsds/22assds3dasfd --query 'Rules[].{Priority:Priority,Host:Conditions[0].Values[0]}'
```

This will return all rule under listener and will return host and priority.

```
  {
        "Priority": "1",
        "Host": "test.example.com"
  }
```

or to get Just ARN of rule

```
aws elbv2 describe-rules --listener-arn arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:34555433333:listener/app/ApplicationLoadBalancer/a333ddsdsddsds/22assds3dasfd --query 'Rules[].RuleArn'
```

As `aws elbv2 describe-rules` does not have an option for the filter that is why you got `Unknown options: --filters`

```
  describe-rules
[--listener-arn <value>]
[--rule-arns <value>]
[--page-size <value>]
[--cli-input-json <value>]
[--starting-token <value>]
[--max-items <value>]
[--generate-cli-skeleton <value>]
```

[describe-rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elbv2/describe-rules.html)

So workaround can list all the rule and grep your desired target group which is attached to rule.

```
aws elbv2 describe-rules --listener-arn arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-west-2:060558051165:listener/app/Prod-Main-Delaers/11a84cfee3fc1e29/37fb4adb7314bac0 | grep -A6 -B6 targetgroupARN
```

Comment: I want to filter based on the `TargetGroupArn` of the rule actually and not all the rules under one listener.

Comment: you can check the documentation no option for the filter, what about the reverse get target group from rule?

Comment: would have been easier if i filter while fetching the records from AWS itself, if not able to get that to work, yeah I will probably try and parse the json and filter it based on the TGArn.

Comment: Yes that's the option but filter not supported here

Answer (score 2):

Adiii is correct to point out that the filter option isn't supported here, however, as the query option is always available, you can get what you want from it, `TargetGroupArn` included.

So with some digging in [JEMSPath](http://jmespath.org/examples.html), the basic solution is:

```
aws elbv2 describe-rules --listener-arn arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:34555433333:listener/app/ApplicationLoadBalancer/a333ddsdsddsds/22assds3dasfd --query 'Rules[].{RuleArn: RuleArn, Actions: Actions[?TargetGroupArn==`arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:34555433333:targetgroup/TG-Test-111111111/ass22dss2dkk`]}|[].RuleArn'
```

Comment: The empty TargetGroupArn in the default rule broke this for me.  I had to exclude it --query 'Rules[:-1].{RuleArn: RuleArn, Actions: Actions[?TargetGroupArn==arn...arn]}|[].RuleArn'

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
aws elbv2 describe-rules --listener-arn 'arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:34555433333:listener/app/ApplicationLoadBalancer/a333ddsdsddsds/22assds3dasfd' \
  --output text \
  --query "Rules[].{RuleArn: RuleArn, Actions:Actions[?TargetGroupArn=='$targetGroupArn'].TargetGroupArn }" | grep -B 1 ACTIONS | grep -v ACTIONS
```

you'll get the RuleArn in text format.
Without the grep, you will get something like:

```
arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:34555433333:listener-rule/app/loadbalancer/a333ddsdsddsds/22assds3dasfd/22assds3dasfs
ACTIONS arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:34555433333:targetgroup/tg/34555433333
```

grep removes the unwanted lines.